# Change kernel time frequency

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to rebuild the Linux kernel with changing the time frequency to 1000 Hz. Can anyone provide me a reference or the instruction to do so.
the current Linux kernel version is (using ubuntu):

```
4.4.0-83-generic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough to download sources. You can actually, on ubuntu, run:

```
apt-get source linux-image-amd64-4.4.0-83-generic
apt-get build-dep linux-image-amd64-4.4.0-83-generic
```

The first command will download the source for that kernel (to the current directory); the second will install all packages needed to build it. When that's done, enter the linux-image folder, and

```
zcat /proc/config.gz > .config
```

This will get the currently-running kernel config into this build area. Finally, `make menuconfig`

will open a text-based menu system. Press `/` to search, and find `HZ`. Browse to the setting, press `<Enter>` to open it, and select 1000. Exit out, saving the config, then `make bzImage modules -j9` to build the kernel (replacing `9` with one more than your CPU core/thread count for speed).

`make install` will put the kernel and modules into `/boot` and `/lib/modules/kernel_name_and_version` respectively.